# Mysql query to filter two or more currencies of products at same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named products and currencies

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_currency` VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `currencies` (
  `currency_name` VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buy_value` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  `sell_value` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I have some records in products table which have USD prices, and others have EUR prices. I also have currency table which is stored with USD,EUR,..etc. buy and sell values. When a visitor inputs USD prices to filter all products by using a search form, the query must check the products which have EUR price values at the same time.

So, how can i do that ?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to have all prices in the same currency and just do the currency conversion for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure of the currencies table. Instead of having a buy and a sell value, I'd have something like

CREATE TABLE `currencies` (
  `source_currency` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `dest_currency` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `value` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
)

And add a set of fake records for the cases when the user wants the same currency (i.e. insert an (EUR, EUR, 1, 1//1/1970), (USD, USD, 1/1/1970)

Then, it becomes a simple (albeit slow) query

```
SELECT products.* FROM products INNER JOIN currency ON price_currency = source_currency WHERE price_min <= price * value AND price * value <= price_max AND dest_currency = desired_currency.
```

Since the multiplication cannot be optimized, it is going to be a full table scan.
Another alternative is to denormalize the products table, to have the price in every possible currency, so when you update the currencies you recalculate the prices. Then searches are trivial (completely indexed) AND you can establish differential prices (a la apple) which you update manually.
Also, if you are using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217 you only need VARCHAR(3), not 5

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful for my app.